Origen datos tiene fecha en formato mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss pero PowerBi lo muestra erróneamente como dd/mm/yyyy
tengo un origen de datos que tiene una columna en formato de fecha mm/dd/yyyyy hh:mm:ss
cuando lo cargo en PowerBi, esas fechas me salen en las visualizaciones como dd/mm/yyyy, mostrando mal las visualizaciones de los datos, ya que toma como día el mes y como mes el día.
He probado a poner un formato personalizado en la vista de modelo, puesto que en los desplegables de formatos, PowerBI no me muestra este tipo de formato, lo cual me parece sorprendente, pero sigue sin mostrarse correctamente en la vista de informe/visualizaciones.

La jerarquía de datos que me sale sigue reconociendo los datos como si fueran de formato dd/mm/yyyy
¿Alguna idea de cómo solucionar este problema? Muchas gracias

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.
